# I'm trying to upgrade grades to the provided dictionary using input command in python

Tags: python

So I'm done with the first part of my program in the second part I have to take the input from user for name and points and the update the grade for the same name in the dictionary and print it. I tried several methods i'm going to post my code down here if anyone can have a look at it and suggest edits accordingly. As you can see the comments on the last those were the commands it tried to update values but got no luck. Thanks in advance

Code:

```py
class Section:
    student = {}     #student dictionary
    instructor = ""  #instructor
    title = ""       #title
    update = {}      #created this to update value
    def __init__(self, stud, inst, tit):
        self.student = stud
        self.instructor = inst
        self.title = tit

    def grading (self, pts):
        if pts > 95:
            lGrade = "A"
        elif pts > 90:
            lGrade = "A-"
        elif pts > 85:
            lGrade = "B+"
        elif pts > 80:
            lGrade = "B"
        elif pts > 75:
            lGrade = "B-"
        elif pts > 70:
            lGrade = "C+"
        elif pts > 65:
            lGrade = "C"
        else:
            lGrade = "F"
        return lGrade

stud = {"Adam": [88,'B'], "Sam": [95,'A'], "Peter": [80,'B-'], "Chris": [70,'C+']}
pythonSection = Section(stud, "John", "Intro to Python")
print("{} is taught by {}".format(pythonSection.title,pythonSection.instructor))
for s in pythonSection.student:
    print("{}".format(pythonSection.student[s][1]))

print(pythonSection.student)
for s in pythonSection. student:
    s = input("Enter name of student:")
    num = input("Enter number:")
    lGrad = pythonSection.grading(num)
    stud.update({s:[student, pts]})
    print(pythonSection)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variables in your `update()` call.

It should be:

```
stud.update({s:[num, lGrad]})
```

Also, you need to convert the input to an integer.

```
num = int(input("Enter number:"))
```